# Change Xamarin form ios launch screen image

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin form cross platform app where I need to change default launch screen image.
I changed launch screen images from Asset catalog then lunch screen but when app is launched image is showing small and centered with background of default xamarin background color.

How do i change that too ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check LaunchScreen.storyboard file?
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

Comment: And bear in mind you must use a storyboard now rather than an image if you want it to work properly on iPhone X

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check your image dimensions and change the background color of the launch screen in the Resources/LaunchScreen.storyboard file (Color tag).

If you need your launch screen background color white:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
```

If you need your launch screen background color black:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" red="0" green="0" blue="0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
```